# How to display and filter deep-nested JSON with angular

Tags: json, angular, angular2-template, angular2-pipe

I have the following JSON object: http://pastebin.com/1TguvZXc

I am trying to access the following property for every model, year, and style: Model.Model[].Years[].Styles[].submodel.modelName

My attempt:

```
<div *ngFor="let model of models?.models">
 <div *ngFor="let submodel of model['years']['styles']">
  Test: {{ submodel.modelName}}
 </div>
</div>
```

This returns no errors however it doesn't display my data.

Additionally, I would like to use the `unique` pipe from `ngx-pipes` to filter out duplicate `modelName`.

How can I display unique values of submodel.modelName?

The Following code:

```
<div *ngFor="let model of models?.models | unique">
  <div *ngFor="let year of model['years']">
    <div *ngFor="let style of year['styles']">
        {{model.name}}, {{ style.submodel.body }}
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

produces the following output:

`2 Series, Coupe
2 Series, Coupe
2 Series, Convertible
2 Series, Convertible
2 Series, Convertible
2 Series, Coupe
2 Series, Convertible
2 Series, Coupe
3 Series, Sedan
3 Series, Sedan
3 Series, Sedan
3 Series, Sedan
3 Series, Wagon
3 Series, Sedan
3 Series, Sedan
3 Series, Wagon
3 Series, Sedan
3 Series, Sedan
3 Series, Sedan
3 Series Gran Turismo, Hatchback
3 Series Gran Turismo, Hatchback
4 Series, Convertible
4 Series, Convertible
4 Series, Convertible
4 Series, Convertible
4 Series, Coupe
4 Series, Coupe
4 Series, Coupe
4 Series, Coupe
4 Series Gran Coupe, Sedan
4 Series Gran Coupe, Sedan
4 Series Gran Coupe, Sedan
4 Series Gran Coupe, Sedan
5 Series, Sedan
5 Series Gran Turismo, Hatchback
5 Series Gran Turismo, Hatchback
5 Series Gran Turismo, Hatchback
6 Series, Convertible
6 Series, Coupe
6 Series, Convertible
6 Series, Convertible
6 Series, Coupe
6 Series, Convertible
6 Series, Coupe
6 Series, Coupe
6 Series Gran Coupe, Sedan
6 Series Gran Coupe, Sedan
6 Series Gran Coupe, Sedan
6 Series Gran Coupe, Sedan
7 Series, Sedan
7 Series, Sedan
7 Series, Sedan
7 Series, Sedan
7 Series, Sedan
7 Series, Sedan
ALPINA B6 Gran Coupe, Sedan
ALPINA B7, Sedan
M2, Coupe
M3, Sedan
M4, Convertible
M4, Coupe
M6, Convertible
M6, Coupe
M6 Gran Coupe, Sedan
X1, SUV
X1, SUV
X3, SUV
X3, SUV
X3, SUV
X3, SUV
X4, SUV
X4, SUV
X5, SUV
X5, SUV
X5, SUV
X5, SUV
X5, SUV
X5 M, SUV
X6, SUV
X6, SUV
X6, SUV
X6 M, SUV
i3, Hatchback
i3, Hatchback
i3, Hatchback
i8, Coupe`

which is far from ideal. I would like to filter the data so it's unique, like this:

`2 Series, Coupe
2 Series, Convertible
3 Series, Sedan
3 Series, Wagon
3 Series Gran Turismo, Hatchback
4 Series, Convertible
4 Series, Coupe
4 Series Gran Coupe, Sedan
5 Series, Sedan
5 Series Gran Turismo, Hatchback
6 Series, Convertible
6 Series, Coupe
6 Series Gran Coupe, Sedan
7 Series, Sedan
ALPINA B6 Gran Coupe, Sedan
ALPINA B7, Sedan
M2, Coupe
M3, Sedan
M4, Convertible
M4, Coupe
M6, Convertible
M6, Coupe
M6 Gran Coupe, Sedan
X1, SUV
X3, SUV
X4, SUV
X5, SUV
X5 M, SUV
X6, SUV
X6 M, SUV
i3, Hatchback
i8, Coupe`

Comment: Have you already tried using the Angular JSON pipe for debugging (`{{ submodel.modelName | json}}`)?

Comment: @stealththeninja yeah I tried that and got nothing as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mental model looks correct (second line) but your `ngFor`s do not. Here's pseudo code of what I'd expect given the shape of your JSON:

```
// div ngFor="let model of models?.models"
//  div ngFor="let year of model.years"
//   div ngFor="let style of year.styles"
//    Test: {{ style.submodel | json }}
```

Looking at the shape of the data with a JSON formatter might help (example: http://jsonformatter.org/).

[Working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/55cGlK)

---

Edit: If you need to filter the array, one solution is a custom pipe. I updated my [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/55cGlK) to include an example. I piped the array inside the `ngFor` directive to the pipe and used a hash map to filter the result. In production code, I'd expect you'd replace the internal of the `createHashKey()` function with a better implementation to classify unique examples.

Template excerpt:

```
<div *ngFor="let model of models?.models">
  <div *ngFor="let year of model.years">
    <div *ngFor="let style of (year.styles | myCustomPipe:'submodel')">
      Test: {{ style.submodel | json }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Custom pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'myCustomPipe'
})
export class MyCustomPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], ...args: string[]): any[] {

    let hashMap = {};
    let filterKey = args[0];

    for (let v of value) {
      const hashKey = createHashKey(v, filterKey);
      hashMap[hashKey] = v;
    }
    return Object.values(hashMap);
  }

}

function createHashKey(obj: any, filterKey: string): string {
  // For demonstration purposes only:
  return JSON.stringify(obj.filterKey);
}
```